# Why AdSense ads on my webpage are appearing on very left totally outside of parent div when data-ad-format=auto but working fine on desktop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, display, adsense

I have a parent div with width 300px and height auto. Inside that div there is an AdSense responsive display ad unit, which I think should take the 300x250 size mostly. But the problem is for some reason I had to set the full width of my webpage to auto, then later I am fixing the total width with javascript. But why this is causing the ads to appear totally outside of the parent div? They are appearing on the very left side. It's on the same level of the parent div but appearing like left 0px on body, totally out of parent div. The data-ad-format="auto" is doing it in mobile devices. But when loading it on desktop the ads are appearing inside the parent div correctly. Using fixed 300x250 ads appearing inside the parent div but not taking the full 300px width. The auto width set for the webpage is causing the problem. But is there any other way like setting a width to body or html?

CSS

```
#Web_1920__1 
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    width: auto;
    height: 5216px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    .display-ad-phone
    {
        position: relative;
        left: 927px;
        width: 306px;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 200px;
        border: 3px rgba(112,112,112,0.45) solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="Web_1920__1">
<script type="text/javascript">
function scaleMe()
  { 
      console.log('hello-here'); 
      if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 615px)").matches) 
      {
           document.getElementById("Web_1920__1").style.width = "2358px";
           document.getElementById("Web_1920__1").style.overflow = "visible";
      }
  }
  scaleMe();
</script>
<div class="display-ad-phone">               
                <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxx"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <!-- Display horizontal -->
                <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                     id="ins-dis-phone-1" 
                     style="display:block"
                     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
                     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxx"
                     data-ad-format="auto"
                     data-full-width-responsive="true">                         
                </ins>
                <script> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); </script>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Why setting width auto to Web_1920__1 div is causing this problem in only mobile devices? The parent div has a specific proper width set, this should be enough. Setting data-ad-format to fluid solves the problem. But I've never seen fluid tag with display ads. Anyone knows how to fix this with data-ad-format auto or with a fixed size ad, while fixed ad appearing smaller issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the parent div with width 300px is always 300px, why not set the ad fixed to 300x250px. This way you don't have to use responsive or auto ad format.

Code:

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxx"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: I have tested it with fixed ad too. But fixed ad is not taking the full width and height either.